# How to display the nested array data in react native from API?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to fetch and display the data from API. Below response i am getting from the API. I want to show the value of "Name" from details array. Kindly help me to resolve this. i have tried below code

```
{ 
   "Success":1,
   "data":[ 
      { 
         "Date":"2019-11-08",
         "Details":[ 
            { 
               "Name":"Name 1",
               "Id":72
            },
            { 
               "Name":"Name 2",
               "Id":73
            }
         ]
      },
       { 
         "Date":"2019-11-09",
         "Details":[ 
            { 
               "Name":"Name 3",
               "Id":72
            },
            { 
               "Name":"Name 4",
               "Id":73
            }
         ]
      }
      ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried the below code but not displaying.render(){
 let movies = this.state.dataSource.map((val) => {
      let sessionList = val.Details.map((val1, key1) => {
        return <View key = {key1} style={styles.view2}>
        <Text>{val1.Name}</Text>
        </View>

      });
    });
 
 return(
 <View>{sessionList}</View>
 )}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript map function can be used for nested iteration.

Consider your data is stored in state as **data**.
If response is received in a variable named response you can set state as

```
this.setState({ data : response.data })
```

Then you can use the below code snippet to iterate through nested object values

{

```
  this.state.data.map((dat, index) => { //Iterate through your data 

    return (
      <View style={styles.selectedCh} key={"outer-" + index}>
        <Text>{dat.Date}</Text>

        {
          dat.Details.map((inner, indexInner) => {  //Iterate through inner Details
            return (
              <View style={{ flex: 1 }} key={"inner-" + indexInner} >
                <Text>{inner.Id}</Text>
                <Text>{inner.Name}</Text>
              </View>
            )
          })

        }

      </View>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ajith. I tried ur code. But I am getting first record from each array. For ex
"Date":"2019-11-08" i am getting "Name":"Name 1" only and  "Date":"2019-11-09" getting "Name":"Name 3"

Comment: Sorry my mistake. it's working now. i made little changes in my code. thanks